# JavaFX popup not working

Tags: javafx, popup, fxml

I’m trying to learn how to get a JavaFX popup window to open from a menu item click. I finally got a new window to open but I can’t seem to make it modal. Here's my code:

Scene 1 FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sceneswitchtest.Scene_1Controller">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="27.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="MenuItemOpenScene2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OpenScene2" text="Open Scene 2" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Popup FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sceneswitchtest.Scene_2Controller">

</AnchorPane>
```

Scene 1 controller:

```
package sceneswitchtest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Scene_1Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar menuBar;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem MenuItemOpenScene2;

    @FXML
    void OpenScene2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) menuBar).getScene().getWindow();
        Parent settingsParent = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("Scene_2.fxml"));
        Scene settingsScene = new Scene(settingsParent);
        appStage.setScene(settingsScene);

//      appStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
//      appStage.initOwner(menuBar.getScene().getWindow());

        appStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    }

}
```

Note: In the above code, the lines commented out failed as well as he use of Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL

Scene 2 (popup) controller:

```
package sceneswitchtest;


public class Scene_2Controller {

}
```

main method:

package sceneswitchtest;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author eric
 */
public class SceneSwitchTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene_1.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to show a popup window or just swich scenes? You ask how to show popup but your code seems to just swich scenes in primary stage. Setting owner of `Stage` to it self does not make sense. If you need to show popup on top of primary stage then create new `Stage` in `OpenScene2` method, set its modality, owner and then `show()`.

Comment: Thanks MBec, I have changed my OpenScene2 method as you suggested and it works!

Comment: BTW, I don't know if you were the one who marked my question down but whoever did, may I point out that there was NOTHING wrong with my question.  As stated in the very beginning I am trying to LEARN this stuff. If I knew how to do it I wouldn't have to ask, would I?  By marking down legitimate questions you are validating the wide spread opinion that this site is trolled by unfriendly purity snobs. 'nuff said.

Comment: No that wasn't my down vote. Your post is ok. Belive me answearing questions on SO is not easy. Most of them are duplicates or `I have a problem, do it for me`. For some people it is easier to post stupid question then write few words in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code changes I made in order to get the popup to work.

```
@FXML
void OpenScene2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent settingsParent = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/sceneswitchtest/Scene_2.fxml"));
    Scene settingsScene = new Scene(settingsParent);
    Stage popup = new Stage();
    popup.setScene(settingsScene);
    popup.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    popup.initOwner(menuBar.getScene().getWindow());

    popup.show();
}
```

I would like to thank MBec for pointing me in the right direction.